# Android: Adding Animation to ListView loses OnItemClick event

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am adding a Animation feature to a listview that can be found [Here](https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/blob/master/ExpandAnimationExample/src/com/udinic/expand_animation_example/ExpandAnimationDemo.java). It seems to be working fine when I click the first time, but the second time it does nothing. Its like it is resetting the On Click event. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

My implementation of class (I am using Fragment class By the way, not sure if that means anything).

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games__main, container, false);
           TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
             GameListModel[] model = new GameListModel[1];
            GameListModel mode =  new GameListModel();
            mode.gameTitle = "Example";
            model[0] = mode;
            GameArrayAdapter adapter = new GameArrayAdapter(getActivity(),model);
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gameListView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.play_challenge);
                    // Creating the expand animation for the item
                    ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

                    // Start the animation on the toolbar
                    toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: i think because u r using fragments the system can restart your app and the fragments when onItemClick is triggered

Comment: Not quite sure if that is true. Anyway, if I remove the animation it works fine.